# Magento Module Creator error when adding a new customer attribute

Tags: php, magento, custom-attributes

I am using [Magento Module Creator](http://silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/) to add a new customer attribute.

I selected "Yes" at Need Add Customer Attribute parameter, add a new attribute, and downloaded source, copied it to my magento directory.

But the back and the front end is not opening.

They are showing me the error

> "Can't retrieve entity config: customer/eav_attribute".

I am using magento 1.6.2 CE.

Comment: How u solved this? Please share..